# XML processing getting different in result in DataWeave playground and Vscode vs Anypoint Studio/Mule runtime

Tags: mule, dataweave, mulesoft, mule4, anypoint-studio

I am processing an XML document (which is HTML with text and elements nested).

Using the following script, Dataweave playground and VScode extension output the correct order of the text/elements:

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json skipNullOn="everywhere"
var xmlString="<root>sometext0<element1>1</element1>sometext2</root>"
---
read(xmlString, 'application/xml')
```

Results in the correct output order:

```
{
  "root": {
    "__text": "sometext0",
    "element1": "1",
    "__text": "sometext2"
  }
}
```

However, the exact same script in Anypoint Studio(7.15, Mule 4.4.0) results in this output with the _text nodes concatenated resulting in losing the correct order:

```
{
  "root": {
    "element1": "1",
    "__text": "sometext0sometext2"
  }
}
```

Does anyone know how I can get Studio/Mule runtime to produce the same correct output as Playground/VSCode please?

Tried running in studio and vscode and playground.

Comment: Did you try setting "application/dw" as output type? Does that change anything? The thing may be that JSON does not support multiple keys with the same name

Comment: Please use the correct formatting for multi line code. The snippets are unreadable. Have you tried in Mule 4.5?

Comment: @aled, fixed the formatting. And yes, tried 4.5, but the same issue unfortunately.

Comment: @JorgeGarcia thanks, yes tried dw but the same issue. Works in playground, but no Mule itself

Comment: When you say it works in Visual Code what extension and versionnare you using and what are the steps for reproduction ?

Comment: @aled DataWeave 2.0 (BETA)v1.2.16 from MuleSoft Inc

I use that or Playground for testing DW for faster feedback than Studio. But then to my suprise, it works differently in Studio and Mule Runtime than in Playground.

Steps to reproduce are run the standalone script in the post at https://dataweave.mulesoft.com/learn/dataweave which produces the result I am expecting.

Then, in Studio, add a transform message with the same script and click preview for the incorrect result

Comment: Instead of preview in Studio execute it. That's the real thing.

Comment: Thanks, yes running in Studio is the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

The DataWeave 2.0 (BETA) extension for Visual Code and the DataWeave playground may not have the same DataWeave engine that actual Mule Runtime versions. They may have different versions of DataWeave embedded. The canonical behavior is whatever a Mule version is doing.

If a Mule version doesn't meet your expectations and you are a customer you coukd open a bug to MuleSoft.